# How to install MarkLogic PHP library with (or without) composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, marklogic, mlphp

I'm trying to follow the instructions on the official github page: https://github.com/marklogic/mlphp

I have composer globally. So I created a composer.json

```
{
  "requires": {
    "MarkLogic\MLPHP" : "dev-master"
  }
}
```

But when I call **composer install** it says:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

And I can see the vendor adds the autoloader, nothing else, no mlphp. I've tried it several other ways, looking at google for hours and nobody seem to have the problem. Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ach, there are typos in the README.  It should read

```
{
    "require": {
        "marklogic/mlphp": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I was almost sure I've tried this version too (lower case all, reverse slash) - but did a final try and works now. Thanks a lot Eric ;)

Comment: The big issue was the type-oh in the slot name: 'require' instead of 'requires'.